Unable to run playwright tests in Jenkins
I am trying to run playwright tests using Jenkins pipeline. Here is the pipeline script:
pipeline {
agent any

// Define the custom workspace directory
environment {
    CUSTOM_WORKSPACE = 'C:\\Automation\\eclat-qa\\Matrix'  // Update this path as needed
}

options {
    // Skip default checkout, optional if you don't need the repository checked out
    skipDefaultCheckout()
}

stages {
    stage('Setup Environment') {
        steps {
            // Use the custom workspace for the setup stage
            dir("${env.CUSTOM_WORKSPACE}") {
                script {
                    // Install npm dependencies
                    bat 'npm install'
                    
                    // Install Playwright browsers
                    bat 'npx playwright install --with-deps'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run Tests in Parallel') {
        parallel {
            stage('Run login.spec.ts') {
                steps {
                    // Use the custom workspace for this stage
                    dir("${env.CUSTOM_WORKSPACE}") {
                        script {
                            // Run the first Playwright test command
                            bat 'npx playwright test src/tests/login.spec.ts'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Run coder.spec.ts') {
                steps {
                    // Use the custom workspace for this stage
                    dir("${env.CUSTOM_WORKSPACE}") {
                        script {
                            // Run the second Playwright test command
                            bat 'npx playwright test src/tests/coder.spec.ts'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Generate Allure Report') {
        steps {
            // Use the custom workspace for this stage
            dir("${env.CUSTOM_WORKSPACE}") {
                script {
                    // Generate Allure report from results
                    bat 'npx allure generate --clean allure-results'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        script {
            // Use the custom workspace for publishing Allure report
            dir("${env.CUSTOM_WORKSPACE}") {
                // Publish the Allure report using the Allure Jenkins plugin
                allure includeProperties: false, jdk: '', results: [[path: 'allure-results']]
            }
        }
    }
}

}
I am trying to run the tests in parallel.
The tests gets stuck after test command is executed.
Console:
C:\Automation\eclat-qa\Matrix>npx playwright test src/tests/login.spec.ts 

C:\Automation\eclat-qa\Matrix>npx playwright test src/tests/coder.spec.ts 

Running 8 tests using 1 worker

Running 4 tests using 1 worker

Sometimes the tests run fine but the above issue is seen most of the time. I also tried using freestyle project but the issue exists there as well.

What is the eventual error(s) seen on console/logs? I don't see any actual errors in the description.

Think from a perspective if somebody else asked you to help in this situation , what other things you would have asked him possibly to provide and then provide those things so that we can help.
